# exception handling in C++

Tags: c++

i have the following program using exception handling.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

void divide(int x,int y,int z)
{
  cout<<"\n Inside function 1 \n";

  if((x-y)!=0)
  {
    int R=z/(x-y);
    cout << "Result =" << R<<"\n";
  } // end of if
  else
  {
    throw(x-y);
  }  // end of else
}   // end of void

int main()
{
  try
  {
    cout<< "Inside try block\n";
    divide(10,20,30);
    divide(10,10,20);
  } //end of try
  catch(int i)
  {
    cout<< "Caught\n";
  }
  return 0;
} //end of main
```

When compiling i get the following errors

> Function throw should have  a prototype.
>
> Undefined symbol "try"
>
> Statement missing ;
>
> Function should return a value.

Please help me.Thanks a lot

Comment: What language are you compiling as? Compile as C++ (g++, not gcc. Or make the project settings in VS C++, not C).

Comment: Use standard headers. `<conio.h>` is non-standard.

Comment: Your code compiles and runs nicely with gcc after changing the include and import the std namespace.

Comment: Why are you throwing an exception here in the first place?  Is this a homework question?

Comment: Would it surprise you to hear that if you compile C++ code with an ancient C compiler, you get errors?

Comment: What compiler are you using? You mention below that you use Turbo C.. I guess it's really Turbo C++, and if I remember correctly, Borland added exception support in Borland C++ 4.5, which wasn't called Turbo C++ anymore. Borland Turbo C++ 3.1 didn't have exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Compile with some non-ancient C++ compiler, use `#include <iostream>` instead of `#include <iostream.h>`, and drop `#include <conio.h>`, then it should just work once you have `using std::cout;`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing

```
#include <exception>
```

Also, typically you should throw an object of a derived class from std::exception

UPDATE: Like the comments point out, including exception is not required. It is required for using std::exception only.

The fix is to use a different compiler. From wikipedia, Turbo C is a C compiler. Thus, it won't support C++ exception handling.

Comment: The header isn't required, though.

Comment: I am using turbo c  and if i include the header file <exception.h> i am getting the error as cannot include the header file #include < exception.h>

Comment: @S.PRATHIBA: None of the standard library headers have a `.h` extension. Read carefully. Also, that sounds like a C compiler to me...not a C++ compiler. There are many more modern and better compilers you should use, for free. See the c++ tag info.

Comment: To expand on GMan's first comment `<exception>` defines some classes (i.e. `std::exception`, `std::bad_exception`) types and functions. As the original code isn't using any of these, adding this include isn't going to help; I'm not sure why this has been voted up.

Answer (score 0):

I think in turbo c if you point your cursor on anything and press F1 it gives the help. Try that with throw.

Answer (score 0):

When you use turbo c , youll get this error. I dont know why, I tried different compiler like online gdb, it worked well there.

You cannot use iostream instead of iostream.h. 
Infact even string is not a data type according to turbo c