# Exception Handling errors in c++

Tags: c++, exception, compiler-errors, programming-languages, turbo-c++

i am unable to do an Exception Handling program in C++ in my MS DOS & Turbo c Compilers. can i have suggestions or any needful statements for that?

Some fatal error of program

[image]

program code

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [exception handling in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644976/exception-handling-in-c)

Comment: If you actually want to be a C++ programmer do yourself a favor and run away from TurboC++.  It is 25+ years old and isn't even C++98 standard complaint.  You'll be doing yourself a disservice by learning C++ with such a compiler.  There are many free compilers like gcc, clang, and msvs that support modern C++ that you can use.

Comment: Hard to believe this isn't trolling...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use exceptions, you need to use a compiler that supports exceptions. Turbo C++ compiler does not support exceptions.

To use Turbo C++, you must not use exceptions.